# Drop and drag several widgets together?

Tags: tkinter, menu, drag-and-drop, widget, frame

I need to add several widgets together and drop and drag them together. The firs way I am thinking is put all widgets in a frame then just drop and drag the frame. But there is a problem that the frame is under the widgets and can not be selected.

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *
WIDTH, HEIGTH = 300, 300







root = Tk()

def do_popup(event):
    try:
        m.tk_popup(event.x_root, event.y_root)
    finally:
        m.grab_release()

root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(WIDTH, HEIGTH))
f1=Frame(root)

def make_draggable(widgets):
    for widget in widgets:
        widget.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event, arg=widgets: on_drag_start(event, arg))
        widget.bind("<B1-Motion>", on_drag_motion)
        widget.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", lambda event, arg=widgets: disaable_bind(event, arg))

def on_drag_start(event,widgets):
    widget = event.widget
    widget = f1
    widget._drag_start_x = event.x
    widget._drag_start_y = event.y

    # for widget in widgets:
    #     widget.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", disaable_bind(widgets))

def on_drag_motion(event):
    widget = event.widget
    widget = f1
    x = widget.winfo_x() - widget._drag_start_x + event.x
    y = widget.winfo_y() - widget._drag_start_y + event.y
    widget.place(x=x, y=y)

def disaable_bind(event,widgets):
    print('disaable_bind')
    for widget in widgets:
        widget.unbind("<Button-1>")
        widget.unbind("<B1-Motion>")
        widget.unbind("<ButtonRelease-1>")

m = Menu(root, tearoff=0)
m.add_command(label="drop and drag", command= lambda: make_draggable([b1,l1]))
m.add_command(label="Copy")
m.add_command(label="Paste")
m.add_command(label="Reload")
m.add_separator()
m.add_command(label="Rename")

l1 = Entry(f1)
b1 = Listbox(f1)
b1.bind("<Button-3>", do_popup)
# b1.place(bordermode=OUTSIDE)
b1.grid(row = 0,column = 0)
l1.grid(row = 1,column = 0)


f1.grid(row = 0,column = 0)
# make_draggable(f1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer? It doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: It's always nice to include explanation to your answers, either by comments on code or by texts